# Can Polish citizens enter Turkey for transit with National ID?

Tags: transit, paperwork, turkey, isl, polish-citizens

Can Polish citizens fly via Turkey just with a national ID (without a visa or passport)? Entry in the destination country is possible I'm sure, but the flight has a transfer in Istanbul Airport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polish citizens are not allowed to enter Turkey with their national ID’s.

[Allowed countries](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa):

> 1. Germany
> 2. Belgium
> 3. France
> 4. Georgia
> 5. The Netherlands
> 6. Spain
> 7. Switzerland
> 8. Italy
> 9. Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus
> 10. Liechtenstein
> 11. Luxemburg
> 12. Malta
> 13. Portugal
> 14. Ukraine
> 15. Greece

Comment: Op doesn't wish to enter Turkey

Comment: @Crazydre I was expecting this to be a partial answer (as allowed by SE network) since I don't know whether OP has to pass through the passport control.

Answer (score 2):

If the trip is in one booking, you do not need to enter Turkey, and therefore don't need a passport.

However, awareness of this fact varies greatly between airport ground staff - anyone not understanding the fact that transit normally doesn't require anything but a connecting ticket (this ignorance is depressingly common) will deny you boarding.

So to be safe, bring your passport, but an e-Visa is **definitely not** needed if the trip is in one booking.

Comment: "awareness of this fact varies greatly between airport ground staff" - not just that. Once I asked *at the embassy* (of a different country) if I need a transit visa, and the clerk rather vehemently insisted that I do, quite contrary to the established rules and also contrary to the truth.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Embassies frequently don't have up-to-date information, or sometimes talk out of their bottoms, so not surprised. Anyway their opinion will hardly matter at check-in.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík The problem is that many staff think TWOV is only a visa exemption, and (incorrectly) that a passport's still needed. For example I e-mailed Belavia airport representatives at different airports asking if I can transit Minsk with just an ID card. Frankfurt and Geneva were adamant that I can, Helsinki and Milan equally adamant that I can't. Equally, when asking Turkish if I can transit Istanbul on my ID (Swedish - officially not accepted for entry to Turkey, although in practice they do let me in on it), Zurich and Stuttgart said no, while Basel and Munich said yes. Bizarre!